# Rmarkdown: How to target code snippets format in html_document?

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

I'm using some custom CSS. Mainly to give my text some left margin. But, it affects the format for the code snippets, giving them a white background, when gray background is what I need.

*Also, I've posted in to r-help mailing list. But got an answer saying it was not the correct place for such a question. And it's difficult posting code within an email.

**1) Using only my CSS:**

-Correct left margins: for the header and the body.
-Code snippet: white background, with syntax highlighting. Background needed to be gray.

I followed this steps (according to this [page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#appearance-and-style)):

```
1) theme: null      
2) css: website2.css (my css document).
```

**2) Using my CSS and a theme:**

Then i've tried using a theme:

```
---
output: 
    html_document:

      theme: cosmo
      css: website2.css

---
```

Results:

-Correct left margins: for the header and the body.
-Code snippet: correct gray background.
-font-family: changed. I need it to remain as "Verdana".

It gives the format i want for the code snipet, but changes the general font, from "Verdana" to "not recognized font".

**My Rmd file:**

````
---
output: 
    html_document:    
      theme: cosmo
      css: website2.css    
---

<!--html_preserve-->
<header id="cabecera">
            <div id="rectangle">  
            </div>
            <div id="titulo">
            <h1>omg.com</h1>
            <p>programmer</p>
            </div>
</header>
<!--/html_preserve-->


<main>

#Heatmap</br>

Hace ... 


En ...oportunidad ... [Tableau](http://www.tableau.com/)....


Por mi parte a inicios del 2015, me interesé por el tema de los heatmaps.

</br>


```{r heatmap, echo = FALSE}
library(d3heatmap)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)


Sys.setenv(LANG = "es")


diasyhoras <- read.csv("diasyhoras.csv", encoding = "")

#Genera visitas random

visits <- runif(nrow(diasyhoras))
visits <- visits * 1000
visits <- round(visits, 0)

#Coloca la cantidad de visitas en la columna Visitas


diasyhoras$Visitas <- visits 


#Genera el heatmap dinámico


d3heatmap(diasyhoras2, scale = "row", colors = "Blues", dendrogram="none",  Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE)



```



```{r ref.label='heatmap', eval = FALSE}
```


##Ggplot2 heatmap 

Esta es la versión con ggplot2...


```{r ,echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(png)
library(grid)
img <- readPNG("HeatMap_Visitasporhora.png")
 grid.raster(img)

```

</main>
````

**My CSS (website2.css):**

```
body { 
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 60px 0px 20px 70px;
}



/*header {
    margin: 0px 200px 20px 0px;
}*/

header h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 0;
}



#rectangle {
    float: left;
    margin: 05px 10px 0px 0px;
    width:10px;
    height:90px;
    background:#37B7DE;
    /*position: relative; #No effect*/

}


/*Main part after header */

main {
    margin: 80px 60px 20px 60px;
}


/*Tamaño letra de los bloques*/

.bloque p,h3,lu,li {
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size: 90%;
}


.bloque h2,a {
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
}


/* Decorado de enlaces */
/*Tienen que estar en una section/div
con la clase "bloque"*/

.bloque a:link {
    color: #1271DE;
}

.bloque a:visited {
    color: #1378BC;
}

.bloque a:hover {
    color: #218CF7;
}

/* ==================== */


button {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I've found [this reference for Rmarkdown](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf).

But, is there some "fonttheme" for html documents? The reference pdf says it only works for beamer.

**UPDATE 2**:

To make it more cleare, here are some images:

**What I want to achieve:**

-See the code is inside a gray brackground. For the syntax highlighting I've used: 'code-prettify'. And for the background CSS. All was done in pure HTML and CSS, without RMarkdown.

[image]

**What I have: Using Rmarkdown and CSS**

I get the left margin, but the background of the code is set to white.

[image]

I hope everything is more clear now. Please, let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to target the code snipets. That's the title of the question. I don't get what i need when using my own CSS.